# Can Tabulator table.getData() to return data with row-ordering matching that on-screen?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm implementing an Excel output function for tables.
The customer expects WYSIWYG output in the generated XLSX.
This all works fine except for the row-ordering in the generated XLSX (for some cases).

For "simple" tables, table.getData("active") works as expected.
The row-order on-screen matches that in the getData results, and reflects both header filters & sorters.

For tables using "groupBy", table.getData("active") does not return rows as on-screen if a column sort is active. The column filters work as expected.

**Is there a way to perform getData and return rows in the order as seen on-screen?**

I also have a table using "dataTree" format. Same issue as for tables with "groupBy".

I keep looking for a getData("wysiwyg"), but I don't think there is one.

Note: The tables have a variable number of columns with various sorters.
I'd like to avoid re-creating the row-ordering on the screen based on raw table data.

Comment: Can you include an example? Screenshots? A jsfiddle maybe?  Don't know what you mean by "WYSIWYG output"

Comment: yes, as Tim said, need an example. my XLSX is WYSIWYG, as it should be

Comment: oh wait, let me check my groupBy tables.... sorry

Comment: yeah, need an example to show problem. My groupBy tables export XLSX filtered,sorted, column order, visibility as expected

Comment: The problem only happens if a column header sort is active. For no active sorts, the order is as expected.

Comment: What I meant by WYSIWYG pertains to having the row order in the visual table reflected in the array returned from getData().